# How to extract first section of a regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

In our application we are adding the ability for a user to search using a regular expression.  However, we need to validate the regular expression string that a user submits.

One restriction / check I need to do on this regular expression string is to ensure the first matching section of the submitted pattern doesn't include any sort of wildcard (e.g. .*).  Essentially we want to ensure there is a literal prefix before any regular expression starts.  (I know, seems a little strange given the point of regex.  However we have noticed much greater performance from our hardware if we enforce this rule).

What I am looking to do is to somehow breakdown the submitted regex string into its various matching sections, extract the first one of these and check its contents against a list of pre-defined strings.  If it contains one of these pre-defined strings, it will fail and the user will be told that particular type of string is not allowed at the beginning of their search.

A very basic example:
If the user submitted the string ".*[A-Z}{4}[0-9]{3}"
This could be broken down into three 'matcher' sections:

- .*
- [A-Z]{4}
- [0-9]{3}

A good demonstration of what I am looking to do would be if you inserted the string ".*[A-Z}{4}[0-9]{3}" into regex101 website, it analyses it, and gives an explanation on the right hand side, breaking down each section of the regex string.  It is essentially this behaviour I need to replicate in my java code - if possible.

I had looked at using the Pattern and Matcher classes. Hoping it would be possible to somehow breakdown the submitted pattern, e.g.

```
private void checkForWildcardCharacter(String regexQuery) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexQuery);      
        // get section 1 of compiled pattern
        if (regexQuerySection1.startsWith(".*")) {
            // throw ValidationFailed exception with explanation;
        }
}
```

I know there are matched groups that you can extract from the Matcher object but this on a result of the pattern being run against a string.

Hope all that makes sense - first time posting a question on SO so may have missed a few helpful parts.

Appreciate it.

**update** for now, I have had to create separate validator class that basically runs a group of regex strings against the user submitted regex string.  Each one essentially checks to ensure the first 'section' of the user's regex adhere's to the restrictions we have to put upon the search feature.
For example, the regex is not allowed to start with a wildcard section (i.e. .*, .+, [A-Za-z0-9]*, etc).

thanks for everyone's info so far, appreciate it.
If anyone has any other ideas please let me know, as my current solution is a little crude.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what the user can't do, but I would make a regex that validates the regex from the user

Comment: If you can find a regex parser you will want to use it in order to assist with your task. Unfortunately the native Java API offers none. The main difficulty is parsing the first token of your regex (in order to check whether it is modified by a quantifier that allows for infinite repetition) and those can take many forms. The most obvious are single characters, character classes, groups, but's there's also escape sequences, shorthand classes, inline flags, etc.

Comment: @Aaron - yeah exactly, so many possibilities to consider when parsing through the submitted regex string.  Was hoping there may already exist some framework/class that did most of that work already.  Or perhaps someone who is a bit more of a regex guru than myself could suggest some regex that does this (just like Arnaud has mentioned above)
Or maybe regex101 wanna give me their parsing code :)

Comment: You might have more luck on the [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). I've googled it for a bit, but regex parser/tokenizer returns tons of parsers & tokenizers based on regex rather than targetting regex, which doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a parsing language like ANTLR? There is a BNF here that could be used to implement this: https://www2.cs.sfu.ca/~cameron/Teaching/384/99-3/regexp-plg.html

Then you would just need to validate the AST has no wildcard nodes.

Answer (score -1):

**I think the example below will give you a hint on what to do.**

```
String text = "abc112def5g64h999";
Pattern onlyNumberPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = onlyNumberPattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()){
    String found = matcher.group();
    System.out.println(found);
}
```

Console:

> 112
>
> 5
>
> 64
>
> 999

Comment: The question is about validating regex patterns, not using one to extract numbers from a string.

Comment: Description of the issue at the level of "write a lot and is incomprehensible." I just wrote an example of how to divide the results into groups. Let him change the regular expressions as he pleases.